# Powershell regex Matches[0].Groups vs Matches.Groups key name based indexing

Tags: regex, powershell

I have just encountered this weird behavior in PowerShell and I'm wondering if there is any logical explanation for it:

After running a regex match on a string:
(Yes, I know, that this might not be the best way to do so, but the issue occurred when building a pipeline and here I only present a stripped down minimal example that still exhibits the behavior.)

```powershell
    $r = "asdf" | Select-String "(?<test>\w+)"
```

The following two expressions print the same results for me:

```powershell
    $r.Matches.Groups
    $r.Matches[0].Groups
```

But out of these two only the second one works:

```powershell
    $r.Matches.Groups['test'] 
    $r.Matches[0].Groups['test']
```

The weirdest thing is that if I use numeric indexes, it works in both cases.

```powershell
    $r.Matches.Groups[0] 
    $r.Matches[0].Groups[0]
```

---

*Edit: I know that in this example the capture group is not necessary at all, but I only wanted to show a simple example that illustrates a problem. Originally I'm working with multiple patterns with multiple capture groups, that I would like to access by name. I know that I could solve it by just using `Matches[0]`, but I'm interested in an explanation.*

Comment: To get the value, you just need `$r.Matches[0].value`. You do not need to access `Groups[0]`. What does your pipeline look like? What is the original issue?

Comment: Originally I'm working with multiple patterns with multiple capture groups, that I would like to access by name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of a PowerShell feature called *property enumeration*.

Since PowerShell 4.0, whenever you reference a member that *doesn't exist*  on a collection type, PowerShell will enumerate the collection and invoke the member on each item.

That means that this expression:

```
$g = $r.Matches.Groups
```

... is basically the same as:

```
$g = foreach($match in $r.Matches){
    foreach($group in $match.Groups){
        $group
    }
}
```

So, at this point, `$g` is no longer a `GroupCollection`- it's just an array of the values that were in any group from any match in `$r.Matches`.

This also explains why the `[0]` index expression works - regular arrays can be indexed into just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for understanding the question and giving a proper answer! :) I was a bit confused when initially I only got a comment that does not at all contain any explanation and two downvotes as well as a close vote, but now that this answer has arrived and two upvotes have balanced out the negativity I feel like this is not a bad question overall and can indeed be understood.

Comment: @Isti115 don't sweat it, it's not a bad question _at all_ - this is one of these things that just intuitively make sense when you've worked with PowerShell >4 long enough, but can be hella confusing if you don't know!